# thymeleaf - how to make two cells in a table merge if one is null or empty?

Tags: html, html-table, thymeleaf

I have a table with 7 columns and I'd like to make two of them merge and display some nice information to the user if there's a null or empty value in a condition check.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
<tr th:each="pojo : ${pojoList}">
    <td th:text="${pojo.a}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.b}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.c}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.d}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.e}"/>

    // here I test if the value is null or empty, if so the next two columns should merge
    <td th:if="${pojo.f.empty}" colspan="2" th:text="#{nice.info}"/>

    // if value is not null or empty, the next two columns gets their respective values
    <td th:text="${pojo.f}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.g}"/>

    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/url/edit(id=${pojo.id})}">
            <img width="20px" height="20px" alt="edit" th:src="@{/assets/img/edit.png}" />
        </a>
        <a th:href="@{/url/remove(id=${pojo.id})}">
            <img width="20px" height="20px" alt="remove" th:src="@{/assets/img/delete.png}" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I used, on a hunch, `<th:block>` like this:

```
<th:block th:if="${pojo.f == null}">
    <td colspan="2" th:text="#{nice.info}"/>
</th:block>
<th:block th:if="${pojo.f != null}">
    <td th:text="${pojo.f}"/>
    <td th:text="${pojo.g}"/>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is not working but you can try the following:

```
// here I test if the value is null or empty, if so the next two columns should merge
<td th:if="${pojo.f.empty}" colspan="2" th:text="#{nice.info}"/>

// if value is not null or empty, the next two columns gets their respective values
<td th:unless="${pojo.f.empty}" th:text="${pojo.f}"/>
<td th:unless="${pojo.f.empty}" th:text="${pojo.g}"/>
```

But I think it is better if you going with the `th:switch` solution ([th:switch](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#swit))